# What are good sources for current developments in the "PDF" scene?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

I need to keep in touch with current developments in the PDF ecosystem. This accounts to

- New standards
- New tools / new versions of tools
- Best practices.

Background is serverside PDF processing (in Java), especially preflighting, normalizing and modifying user-generated (i.e. arbitrary) PDF documents.

Some sources I have found so far:

- [http://www.pdfzone.de/](http://www.pdfzone.de/virthos.php) (german)
- [PDF-Lib cookbook](http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/browse-all-topics/) (does not really count, as it is vendor-specific)

Apart from that, googling only brought up horribly outdated sites that I would not trust to keep me updated about what's going on at the bleeding edge.

What am I missing?

---

To sum up the answers I got so far, I made a condensed list:

#### Blogs

- [Inside PDF](http://blogs.adobe.com/insidepdf/)
- [Adobe Reader blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/adobereader/)
- [PDF dev junkie](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/)
- ["Echo chamber" of the "IT matters" blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfitmatters/category/echo-chamber)

*(all of the above are hosted on adobe.com meaning that they might be biased)*

#### Aggregator sites

- [Planet PDF](http://www.planetpdf.com/) (also has a [stack exchange site](http://qa.planetpdf.com/))

#### Vendor sites

- [Bruno Lowagie's Blog (IText)](http://www.lowagie.com/)
- [ICE PDF site](http://www.icepdf.org/) (They don't really have a news page or blog but a [wiki](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/PDF))
- [JPedal blog](http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/)
- [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) (this is a maven site)
- [Big Faceless blog](http://bfo.com/blog)

Comment: There's a *bleeding edge* of PDF?

Comment: @Greg Well ... you know, not in the usual, special sense. But still, some pdf tools are being developed, right? So there needs to be something at least similar to a bleeding edge. Even if it's a bit slow.

Comment: version 1.7 of pdf is an iso standard (n° 32000) since 2008 so no much changes on the bleeding edge... http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf

Comment: So, the PDF standard is obviously more or less fixed. Still, software is being developed, right? What about progress in this field?

Comment: My eyes frequently bleed when writing code to manipulate PDFs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Planetpdf is a good place for news and has just done a major revamp (http://www.planetpdf.com/). It also has a forum for asking PDF questions.

Acrobat X has only just come out so there is lots of developments in the PDF world.

Various actively developed Java tools (ie IText, Icepdf, JPedal, PdfBox) have pretty active sites with blogs, forums and regular new releases. Manning has just issued a new version of 'IText in Action'

Adobe also has lots of content on its sites.

Answer (score 1):

All of the following are hosted @ adobe.com:

- [Blog of James King](http://blogs.adobe.com/insidepdf/) (principal architect of PDF file format)
- [Adobe Reader Blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/adobereader/)
- [The PDF Developer Junkie Blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/)

Answer (score 0):

I expect [Adobe's PDF SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/library.html) is the good place to start.  It does require you filling out a form though.

Answer (score 0):

Planet PDF is pretty good. If you require information on PDF/A I would recommend visiting PDF/A Competence Center.

Also, you may want to follow our blog http://bfo.com/blog/ or Twitter page.